# How to map one XML with different XML through Data mapper in mule

Tags: mule, mule-component

I have an XML as below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns2:trigger xmlns:ns2="http://www.someurl.com/" id="1001">
    <changes>
        <change id="5" userName="12334">
            <UserField name="Organisation">Organisation 1</UserField>
            <UserField name="Age"/>
            <UserField name="First name">1</UserField>
        </change>
        <change id="1" userName="abc">
            <UserField name="Organisation">Organisation 1</UserField>
            <UserField name="Age"/>
            <UserField name="First name">Name</UserField>
        </change>
        <change employeeId="123" id="2" userName="hr"> 
            <UserField id="8" name="Organisation">Firma AS</UserField>
            <UserField id="33" name="Age"/>
            <UserField id="2" name="Last name">HR</UserField>
        </change>
        <change employeeId="q123" id="16" userName="Ashish">
           <UserField name="Organisation">Organisation 1</UserField>
            <UserField name="Age"/>
            <UserField name="Last name">Ashish Singh</UserField>
        </change>
    </changes>
</ns2:trigger>
```

I want to generate another XML from above XML which will look like as below:

```
<DATA>
    <SAVE>
        <EMPLOYEE>
            <FIRST_NAME>1</FIRST_NAME>
            <AGE></AGE>
            <ORGANIZATION>Organisation 1</ORGANIZATION>
        </EMPLOYEE>
        <EMPLOYEE>
             <FIRST_NAME>Name</FIRST_NAME>
            <AGE></AGE>
            <ORGANIZATION>Organisation 1</ORGANIZATION>
        </EMPLOYEE>
        <EMPLOYEE>
            <LAST_NAME>HR</LAST_NAME>
            <AGE></AGE>
            <ORGANIZATION>Organisation 1</ORGANIZATION>
        </EMPLOYEE>
        <EMPLOYEE>
             <LAST_NAME>Ashish Singh</LAST_NAME>
            <AGE></AGE>
            <ORGANIZATION>Organisation 1</ORGANIZATION>
        </EMPLOYEE>

    </SAVE>
</DATA>
```

I have researched on data mapper and tried to get required XML but I am not able to achieve it. I am doing this mapping and it is giving me following output:

[image: mapping]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <save>
    <employee>
      <name>Organisation</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
      <name>Age</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
      <name>First name</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
      <name>Organisation</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
      <name>Age</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
      <name>First name</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
      <name>Organisation</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
      <name>Age</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
      <name>Last name</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
      <name>Organisation</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
      <name>Age</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
      <name>Last name</name>
    </employee>
  </save>
</data>
```

Please tell me how to do it through data mapper.

Answer (score 1):

Your target mapping structure looks incorrect to me. You will need to amend or re-create this.

I'd suggest you re-create the metadata based on the sample XML you've provided above. In your DataMapper window, above the output mapping box, hit the little wand button and select `Re-Create Metadata`. Then you want to generate it from a sample file and use the XML you've provided.